# what does it mean by $\# \{ i : x_i \le t \}$?

Tags: notation, simple-functions

I was reading through some manuscript and wanted to try to implement some stuff mentioned in the text. I came across this equation

equation $= \# \{ i : x(i) \le t \}$

I went through a couple of references and just wanna confirm that what I understand is correct.

From what I understand the equation is saying the number of element in x that is smaller and equal to t?

Comment: It depends on $i$; if it is an *index* (i.e. a natural number), then $x(i)$ is a *sequence* ($x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$) and thus the set is the set of values of $i$ such that $x(i) \le t$.

Comment: I would read this as "The number of (#) elements (named $i$) such that (:) the value of $x(i)$ is less than or equal to $t$"  For example, if you are talking about a permutation matrix and for its corresponding permutation, this would count the number of nonzero entries at or above the diagonal.

Comment: It will vary of course based on exact context, but it seems likely that $x$ is a sequence or a permutation or some other common type of map, likely but not necessarily on a finite set.  Otherwise, it doesn't necessarily make sense to try to count things here.

Comment: Hello both, thanks for the reply. i in this case is the index, so with # i am counting the size of set right?

Comment: Thanks! this there any way I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is better to use the form :

> $\# \{ i : x_i \le t \}$.

In this way, we have a *sequence* $(x_i)$ [i.e. $x_0,x_1, x_2,\ldots$] and the set $\{ i : x_i \le t \}$ is the set of values of $i$ such that $x_i \le t$.

Thus, because [the symbol $\#$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) is often used to count the number of elements of a set, the formula is counting the number of element in $(x_i)$ that are smaller-or-equal to $t$.